# Sorting Truncated Date in Solr

Tags: sorting, date, solr, truncated

I am currently using solr 7.1.0.  I have indexed a few documents which have a date associated with it.

The Managed schema configuration for that field is :

```xml
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
<field name="Published_Date" type="pdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Example of few values are :

```
"Published_Date":"2019-10-25T00:00:00Z",
"Published_Date":"2019-10-21T10:00:00Z"
```

Please help me in finding how I could achieve the following
I want to sort the documents based on these Published_Date parameters but only on the day(not the time/timezones)
Sorting on the basis of

```
"Published_Date":'2019-10-25'
```

Comment: I have no idea if this works for the `sort` parameter, but you can usually use date math to round dates to just the DAY part - `Published_Date/DAY`. If that doesn't work for sorting, I'd probably index the date as a separate field to avoid a lot of processing if you want to use that sort often.

Comment: @MatsLindh The math formatting works while performing the actual query(`q` field).
It doesn't seem to work on the `sort` parameter.

How/what would be the schema if you did index it to as a separate field, Is there a way to index the day/month/year formatting only?

Comment: Depending on where you're getting the data from you could either handle it when you're indexing documents in your own code and round the date down, or you can do it in a update request processor chain on the Solr side. If you're using DIH you can do it either in SQL or in a replace transformer.

Comment: 'Round the date down' - The `Solr.DatePointField` stores the date in the UTC format. with the Time and Timezone information. so each time I just provide the rounded off values also- the date gets indexed the format mentioned in the question. :(
i dont have any experience wrt to `request processor chain`.

Comment: Yes, the format will contain the date with time and timezone information. That's a display consideration you should handle in your frontend. As long as the values sort correctly, the actual order of the documents should be what you want.